# Finding a user by Discord Discrim via Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Once again, I'm into Discord bot coding.

This time, I'm trying to make a way to find a user by it's Discrim.
Getting the user by it's Discrim, would easly allow to do another things, like, find his ID, that by the meaning time, the profile picture, name...

According to discord.py, we need to use get_user_info(user_id).
But finding someone's ID can be hard for some, so if I could get the ID by the discrim and then do whatever, would be much easier.

I tried do the following:

```
DefaultUser = discord.User
hi = DiscrimIguess[0]
hi2 = discord.User.discriminator.hi
```

You get the"DiscrimIguess", when the user types the command plus the discrim.

Any way I can do this? Because it won't work.

Comment: Who says getting a user's id is hard? `\@user` and you get their id in the form `<@user_id>`. If you don't want to do that, switch on developer mode from your `settings > appearance` and when you right click a user you get their id. Furthermore, if you tag a user and you print it to your console, it already appears in the form `<@user_id>`

Comment: Alright. I've tried using that get_user_info, and, I did this: `OurUser= self.get_user_info(userId)` || Then made it send a message with the  "OurUser" and it said that couldn't convert to a simple str.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **you should not be using a discrim to find a user.** IDs are unique, discrims are not.

Discrims are given to each member to help determine who is who when two members share the same name (i.e. test#0001 and test#0002 are different people)

Anyway, while you cannot find a single specific user by discrims, you can find a list of all the users who share a discrim by using [`Client.get_all_members`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)

```
p = client.get_all_members()
found_members = filter(lambda m: m.discriminator==DiscrimIguess[0], p)
```

If you also have a username you can narrow that list down to a single member and then get the ID from that.

```
member = discord.utils.get(found_members, name=username)
id = member.id
```

This method only works for finding members who share a server with the bot. To find users who do not share a server with the bot, you *must* have an ID already for [`Client.get_user_info'](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info)