# Get Discord user ID from username

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If I have a user's Discord name and discriminator as a string (e.g `ExampleUser#1234`) how can I get their user ID from it? I've found `get_user(id)`, but that returns a user object from an ID. I'm using Python and Discord.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line just do

```py
discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), name="ExampleUser", discriminator="1234").id
```

notice the `.id` at the end, that gives you the ID of that person.
Also for the discriminator part don't include the hash(#)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in this excellent answer by [Sam Rockett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8360823/sam-rockett) ([Finding a User ID by Discord Discrim via Python (1st ans)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45382318/8551315) you can try this:

```
p = client.get_all_members()
found_members = filter(lambda m: m.discriminator==your_discrim, p)
member = discord.utils.get(found_members, name=your_username)
id = member.id
```

P.S. This snippet only works for finding members who share a server with the bot. To find users who do not share a server with the bot, you must have already an ID.

Comment: You can pass both the name and discriminator to `get`:  `get(client.get_all_members(), name=name, discriminator=discriminator)`

Answer (score -1):

I will tell you the best way to do this. You have to search the member user and matching username with member user.

```
message.guild.members.find(m => m.user.username === 'USERNAME').user.id
```

https://thediscordbots.blogspot.com/2019/10/what-are-discord-bots-really-and-which.html

Comment: Bro this is discord.js while the question is for Discord.py as you can see in the question and tags