# Python Discord - Get user id or user object from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I tried like the solution given at [Get Discord user ID from username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649868/get-discord-user-id-from-username), but both solutions return `None`. What am I doing wrong?

```py
async def name_to_user_object(self, ctx, user):
    user = user.split("#")
    user_id = discord.utils.get(self.bot.get_all_members(), name=user[0], discriminator=user[1]).id
    return user_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can take use of `MemberConverter` or `UserConverter`, simply typehint the `user` argument to `discord.Member` or `discord.User` and library will do the rest for you, here's how:

```py
async def name_to_user_object(self, ctx, user: discord.Member): # or `discord.User`
    print(user, type(user)) # it will already be a `discord.Member` or `discord.User` obj
```

Reference:

- [`MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=memberconverter#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter)
- [`UserConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=usercon#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter)

Comment: For me, this returns username#1234 <class 'str'>

Comment: It works flawlessly for me, are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Pretty sure. Found a workaround by using a user object in the first place.